# table included in merge replication has all its data disposed when execute

Tags: sql-server

I have merge replication between two databases, "db1" as a publisher and "db2"
as a subscriber.

Just adding one row to "table1" included in db2 and then right clicking on data then execute I got all its data disposed. Even if I try to copy its data manually from table1 in the published I got a message that table1 is being upgraded by the publisher and I cannot insert.

The table's primary key is foreign key in other tables.

How is the content permitted to delete?

[image: the image attached display what i exactly did]]

Comment: You are still more likely to get better help on your [dba.stackexchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221916/table-included-in-merge-replication-has-all-its-data-disposed-when-execute) on that site, where more DBA's reside.

Comment: i did posted the same question  on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ with no answer

Comment: I understand, I'm just letting you know that's likely where you are going to get the answer because it's so admin specific (not programming).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for you advice